# Analytic proof of sequence convergence from first principles

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Given $a_1=\sqrt2$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}$, I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n} = 2$ and I've seen several, very clever and quite simple algebraic methods to show it. It's also an easy enough proof if one simply uses the accepted algebra of limits as they apply to exponents. But what I haven't seen and can't seem to figure out for myself is an elegant proof from first principles using the $\epsilon-N$ definition for convergence of an infinite sequence. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, one needs to show in the first place that the limit does exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1}-2=\frac{\sqrt2(a_n-2)}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{2}},$$
which gives that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $a_n<2$ by induction (because $a_1<2$).

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{\sqrt{a_n}(2-a_n)}{\sqrt2+\sqrt{a_n}}>0,$$
which gives that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing and we are done!

Comment: I'm afraid that your very first statement eludes me. To clarify, I was wanting to prove that: given any $\epsilon>0$ no matter how small, there exists an N such that $|{a_n-2}|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. In other words, an explicit algebraic expression for N in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: @cpw I proved that $a$ increasing and there is $A$, for wich $a_n<A$. Thus, $a$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

One idea is find the general term:

$$a_{n+1}=2^{1/2}a_n^{1/2}=2^{(1/2+1/4)}a_{n-1}^{1/4}=\dots=2^{(1/2+1/4+\dots+1/2^n)}a_{1}^{1/2^{n}}$$

so,

$$a_{n}=2^{1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}$$

now you can use $\epsilon-N$ definition.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

By induction, we prove that
$$1\le a_n \le 2$$
and
$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge 1$$

the limit $L $ Satisfies

$$L^2=2L $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$a_n=2^{1-2^{-n}}$$

For a given $\epsilon > 0$ we want to find $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n>N \implies |a_n-2|<\epsilon$$

Let $$N=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln\left(\frac{2}{2-\epsilon}\right)}\right)}{\ln(2)}$$ if $\epsilon<2$ or else let $$N=1.$$